# How to redirect systemd started service output to a file?

Tags: 16.04, system, systemd, logging, monitoring

I have just started playing with [prometheus](https://prometheus.io/) and installed it as a service.

Initially I started it in a screen and let it run but I'd like to run it as a systemd managed service and thus would like to redirect all it's output to a log file however ***ExecStart=/opt/prometheus/prometheus/prometheus &> /opt/prometheus/prometheus/prometheus.log*** results in an error, but if I remove the redirection systemd still reports a timeout error but the service is started and running successfully.
I did however find [this article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-prometheus-to-monitor-your-ubuntu-14-04-server) which is the next best thing I've found thus far but it is not what I want to achieve.

Edit: error message as requested

```
- Subject: Unit prometheus.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit prometheus.service has begun starting up.
Sep 04 09:14:13 prometheus prometheus[4036]: prometheus: error: unexpected >>
Sep 04 09:14:13 prometheus systemd[1]: prometheus.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Sep 04 09:14:13 prometheus systemd[1]: Failed to start Prometheus monitoring system for monitoring system nodes and services.
-- Subject: Unit prometheus.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit prometheus.service has failed.
--
-- The result is failed.
```

Comment: This `ExecStart=` line is from `/lib/systemd/system/prometheus.service`, isn't it? Did you try to edit it using `sudo systemctl edit --full prometheus`? Please add the error messages you're receiving in their entirety to your question using a code block (`{}` button).

Comment: "to a log file" systemd has a log itself called "journal" see https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-journald.service.html

Comment: @dessert No I created the service file myself so the path is the path where I installed prometheus, I'll edit to reflect the path and add error message

Comment: @Rinzwind Thanks, but I want to redirect the output to a file. Besides if I start the service without redirection it just reports a timeout error in starting the service